# Save all data in textbox and datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a datagridview where I want to save the product code only and also I have textboxes; totalamount, cash, change. How do I save the product code and textboxes value to database? I tried my code below but its save only one row. Thanks!!

[datatable and textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACord.png)

**Code:**

```
   Public Sub addTransaction()
        Try
            dbConnection()
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbltransactions(trans_number, trans_total, trans_cash, trans_change, trans_date, trans_time, trans_month, trans_day, trans_year, invoice_number, product_code) VALUES(@trans_number, @trans_total, @trans_cash, @trans_change, @trans_date, @trans_time, @trans_month, @trans_day, @trans_year, @trans_invoice, @product_code);"
            command = New SqlCommand
            With command
                .Connection = connection
                .CommandText = insert_query
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_number", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = CashierView.txtTransactionID.Text})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_total", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = CashierView.txtTotalAmount.Text})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_cash", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = CashierView.txtTendered.Text})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_change", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = CashierView.txtChange.Text})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_date", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = Date.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_time", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_month", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = Date.Now.ToString("MMMM")})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_day", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = Date.Now.ToString("dd")})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_year", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy")})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_invoice", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = CashierView.lblInvoiceNumber.Text})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@product_code", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar})
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In CashierView.ProductsListDGV.Rows
                    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                        .Parameters("@product_code").Value = row.Cells(0).Value
                        .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If
                Next
            End With
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            connection.Close()
            command.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: What r u tryin to do exactly ? are u tryin to insert the data from the dgvws cell(0) into the db ?

Comment: Yes and also the textboxes and date, time, month, day and year.

Comment: Then y r u using the `For each` statement ? Just use `dgvw.SelectedRows(dgvw.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value`

Comment: I'm using for each to save all rows in datagridview, and also why should I use the SelectedRows?

Comment: what do u mean by **Save all rows in datagridview**?

Comment: ow....and sorry for suggesting `selectedrows`

Comment: If you took the time to learn how the various NET DB Providers work and what they are capable of, you could write much. much less code.  The first mistake is thinking that  data goes into or comes out of a `DataGridView`  
 Used properly it simply provides a *View* of the *Data* to the user in a *Grid* - hence the clever name.

Comment: @zackraiyan, please review this recommendation. [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345652/2592875](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345652/2592875)

Comment: If you haven't gone to far with this project, I would dump the DB design and try again. With all the lovely data types SQL Server provides why would you store numbers, currency, dates etc. as varchar? The sale would be saved to two tables, a sales table and a sale details. That is the beauty of a relational database, you don't have to repeat all that data for every item in the datagrid.